# How can I persist auth state in a nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, I am learning NodeJs by creating this backend that fetches some data from a third-party API, the API requires auth. I couldn't figure out how to avoid sending an auth request to the third-party API whenever I wanted to fetch data from it. is there any way I could store the auth state in the app?

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const AUTH_URL = process.env.AUTH_URL;
const REPORT_BASE_URL = process.env.REPORT_BASE_URL;
const X_API_KEY = process.env.X_API_KEY;

const getCompanies = async (req, res) => {
    let idToken;

    // auth
    const authPayload = JSON.stringify({
        // ...
    });

    const config = {
        method: "post",
        // ...
    };

    try {
        const { data } = await axios(config);
        idToken = data.idToken; // set idToken necessary for fetching companies
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // get company by full text query
    const { full_text_query } = req.query;

    if (!full_text_query)
        return res.send("No full_text_query parameter provided");

    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            `${REPORT_BASE_URL}/companies?full_text_query=${full_text_query}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    "x-api-key": X_API_KEY,
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    authorization: idToken,
                },
            }
        );

        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    getCompanies,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break out a function like `fetchIdToken` and store a `Promise` that resolves with the `idToken` in memory.

```js
let idTokenPromise;
async function fetchIdToken () {
  if (idTokenPromise) return idTokenPromise;
  return idTokenPromise = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    ...
    resolve(data.idToken);
  })
}
```

You can then use `await fetchIdToken()` at the start of `getCompanies`.

You can also just store the `idToken` in memory. This is slightly simpler, but does mean that you can have a race-condition when multiple `getCompanies` requests happen at the same time:

```js
let idToken;
async function fetchIdToken () {
  if (idToken) return idToken;

  ...
  idToken = data.idToken;
  return idToken;
}
```

Comment: I went with the second solution but didn't know about the race-condition. Thank you, I will go with the promise implementation.